# Rspec not testing render, won't allow us to stub render action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Rails 5.0.0.1
Rspec 3.5.4
Ruby 2.3.1

We have been trying to provide test coverage for our rails application. We have a rescue in a private method that Rspec is not reaching.

Rspec:

```
it 'returns 200 after 404 from GET #edit error' do
  allow(controller).to receive(:getpackages).and_return(URI::InvalidURIError)    
  expect(response.code).to eq(200) # => covers the 200
  expect(response).to render_template('errors/5xx') # => doesn't read 
end
```

Rails:

```
private

def set_package
  @package = PackageServices.getpackage params[:id]
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  render 'errors/5xx'
end
```

Error message:

```
expecting <"errors/5xx"> but rendering with <[]>
  ./spec/controllers/packages_controller_spec.rb:139:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  -e:1:in `load'
  -e:1:in `<main>'
```

We have tried to assert_template, tried to stub it using stub_template, installed a gem rails-controller-testing (not rspec), but we have run out of ideas and every google link is purple. Is this a bug in Rspec or are we going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I  believe the stabbing was incorrect. Try the following code, it should work.

```
context 'URI is invalid' do
  before do
    allow(PackageServices).toreceive(:getpackage).and_raise(URI::InvalidURIError)
  end

  it 'returns 200 after 404 from GET #edit error' do  
    expect(response.code).to eq(200) # => covers the 200
    expect(response).to render_template('errors/5xx') # => doesn't read 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! We are still getting the same error :<code>expecting <"errors/5xx"> but rendering with <[]>
./spec/controllers/packages_controller_spec.rb:91:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'</code> I think we need to stub the render in order to provide code coverage but can't find a way to do it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This works: `context 'URI is invalid' do
      before do
        allow(PackageServices).to receive(:getpackage).and_raise(URI::InvalidURIError)
      end

      it 'returns 200 after 404 from GET #edit error' do
        allow(controller).to receive(:ensure_logged_in).and_return(true)
        get :edit, params: { id: 1 }
        expect(response.code).to eq('200')
        expect(response).to render_template('errors/5xx') 
      end
    end`

Comment: @rkentmc `ensure_logged_in` wasn't in the code you've provided, so I could only base my answer on what I saw

Comment: Just updating for the entry in case some one else has a similar issue. We were not calling the right resource, in this case it would be an instance of our get method